# Send Emoji from EditText to Server

Tags: java, android, unicode, emoji, unicode-escapes

I send the text from an EditText field to my server and store it in a Mysql database. It works fine. But when I try to send emojis it only sends the text. So I google something and find out that the only solution is to convert the EditText Value.

I tried the following:

```
String toServer = EditText.getText().getString();
String toServerUnicodeEncoded = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(toServer);
```

Now the Emojis have the java unicode format. Nearly...

For example. It should be "\u2764" but on my server it gets "u2764". So it don't send the "\". I tried to send the string "\u2764" to the server. it works.

Is there somebody who can tell me why it didn't send the correct "\u2764" and remove the "\"...

Comment: Please provide more details. On which place backslash is removed? There are too many places where things can go wrong. How do you send data to backend? Via JSON or XML? Which parser and with which configs do you parse those? What is hidden under StringEscapeUtils?

Comment: The backslash is removed in the App. So I get the Edittext and its still correct with backslash. Then I send the data with volley/json to my PHP Script. But my PHP Script gets it without backslash. But it must be in the app because if I create a string with "\u2764" and send it to my PHP Script it works.

Comment: Can you please attach JSON send by application to PHP backend to the post?

Answer (score 0):

Many products use the backslash `\` as an 'escape' character.  They act on the character and otherwise throw it away.

If there is no action to be performed by the product, it is likely to simply throw it away.

Some products will treat `\u2764` as a heavy black heart (`❤`), replacing the 6 bytes by the 3-byte UTF-8 character with hex `E29DA4`.

Others will say "Hmmm, I don't do anything with a `u` after a backslash, so I will simply toss the backslash."  This turns the 6 characters `\u2764` into the 5 characters `u2764`.

Where did `\u2764` come from?  If it was from the PHP `json_encode`, then tack on `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` as a second argument.